# Existence of solution for Poisson problem with pure Neumann BCs

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis

Hello all,

Does the following boundary value problem admit unique solutions $q$:

$- \Delta q + \beta q = f$,  $x \in \Omega$

$ \nabla q \cdot \vec{n} = g $, $x \in \Gamma := \partial \Omega$,

where $\beta > 0$ is reasonably small? I am not clear if the pure Neumann boundary conditions make the solution non-unique; does the inhomogeneity in the volume equation take care of this problem? What are the spaces for $f$ and $g$ such that we have uniqueness?

Comment: This is homework. Not suitable for MO.

Comment: This is not homework :) My question stems from a finite-difference discretization of such a PDE problem that seems to have trouble converging to a solution upon mesh refinement.

If you cannot give the answer out right, could you point me to a reference that discusses this particular form of the equation? I have not been able to find a discussion of this case in the literature, and my experience with theoretical PDE analysis is limited at best, that is, I am not so familiar with standard PDE solution existence proofs.

Comment: A couple remarks: The β parameter is redundant, as you can divide by it and absorb it into $f$. Or did you not intend the β in front of the Laplacian? Also, this being a linear system, the right hand side has no bearing on the uniqueness of any solution. If the homogeneous system has a non-zero solution, then solutions are not unique (if they exist). Finally, you can gain some insight from looking at the one-dimensional case, with Ω an interval. At least it should tell you what to expect.

Comment: yes the $\beta$ parameter should not be in front of the laplacian. thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Assuming you are dealing with classical solutions, the difference $q' = q_1 - q_2$ of two solutions solves the homogeneous Neumann problem $-\triangle q' + \beta q' = 0$ with 0 Neumann condition. Now use the strong maximum principle and Hopf lemma.

Comment: The PDE text by Evans has a good, fairly introductory discussion for elliptic equations of this kind. For a 'reasonable' domain and consistent discretization, your FD method should converge for this problem. 

Answer (score 3):

A weak form of your BVP is $a(q,v)=\ell(v)$ where $a(q,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla q\cdot\nabla v\,dx+\int_{\Omega}\beta qv\,dx$ and $\ell(v)=\int_{\Omega}fv\,dx+\int_{\partial\Omega}gv\,ds$ with $q,v\in H^1(\Omega)$.
If $\beta>0$, the bilinear form is coercive and continuous in $H^1(\Omega)$. Thus, apply Lax-Milgram and you get existence, uniqueness and stability in $H^1(\Omega)$. Stability now depends on the value of $\beta$.